# SVM - AMD VM extensions = 0 (1)

Tags: virtualbox

I get error while installing Android OS on Virtualbox-5.0_5.0.14-105127:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill the idle task!
```

Virtualbox->Settings->System->Acceleration->Default (all enabled)

- Host OS - Linux Mint 17.3
- motherboard - FM2A85X-ITX
- CPU - A10-5800K

In [log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lhpj24s6ljuso8/log?dl=0):
    SVM - AMD VM extensions = 0 (1)

Tried different versions of Virtualbox. 
Performed, but without success:

```
sudo killall VBoxSVC
export VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE=true
VirtualBox
```

At the same time on the same machine with Windows 7, but in Virtualbox 4.2.x it's ok.

How to overcome the problem?